# Why does jumping off a merry go round in the radial direction cause no change in rotation speed?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque

Suppose a man is standing on a merry-go-round which is rotating with some speed, if he jumps out in the radial direction, then the rotation speed of the merry-go-round is unaffected. But I don't understand why should this be so?

I saw this [article discussing it](https://www.wired.com/2011/01/jumping-off-a-merry-go-round/), but they don't really explain what's going on, they just say "no torque" without giving the reason why there shouldn't be torque. However from my calculations I think there be some form of torque if he jumps of radially.

As we can see, to accomplish a "jump" , he has to apply a jump force 'J' onto the board to push himself away. This force produces a torque onto the rotating disc as, $ \vec{r} \times F = \vec{ \tau}$. So, am I doing something wrong, or is there some technical incorrectness in the article?

Edit: I'm looking for both mathematical description and intuition of it. An intuition I came up myself is that that the man literally "jumps" away with his angular momentum ( assuming the article is right in describing the phenomena)

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the "jump force" $\vec{J}$ will in fact exert a torque on the merry-go-round, due to its upward component.  But this torque would tend to twist the disc around an axis lying in the plane of the disc, and the disc presumably can't rotate freely about an axis lying in its plane.  (The bearing the merry-go-round is mounted on can exert a torque about a horizontal axis.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a stationary merry-go-round. Walk to the edge of the platform and jump radially away from the center.

Does the merry-go-round start spinning? No, because you jumped at an angle that's parallel to the moment arm. Torque isn't just force times length, it's the cross-product of two vectors.

$\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$
$ = r F \text{sin}(\theta) \hat{n}$

Where $r = \left|\vec{r}\right| $, $F = \left|\vec{F}\right|$, $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$, and $\hat{n}$ (the normal vector) is the unit vector perpendicular to the plane containing $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$.

Because the merry-go-round will have a spindle that only rotates on one axis, we can ignore components of $\vec{F}$ that aren't in the rotational plane of the platform, and $\hat{n}$ will point straight up (or down, depending on the coordinate system). $r$ will simply be the distance between the edge of the platform you jumped from and the central spindle, and $F$ will be however much force you can jump with.

The critical part of the equation is $\text{sin}(\theta)$. If you jump in a direction perpendicular to $\vec{r}$ (forward or backward relative to the edge's motion), $\theta=\pm 90°$, so $\text{sin}(\theta) = \pm 1$. This is the limiting case where torque is just force times distance, rotating around the vertical axis, with torque being backward or forward (plus or minus) depending on which way you jumped.

[image: Man jumping tangentially to the disc edge with ninety degrees between the force and radial vectors.]

But if you jump straight away from the center, $\vec{F}$ is pointing straight along $\vec{r}$, so $\theta=0°$ and $\text{sin}(\theta) = 0$. Force times distance times zero is no torque at all.

[image: Man jumping radially outwards with zero degrees between the force and radial vectors.]

Likewise, jumping towards the center would make $\theta=180°$ and we still have $\text{sin}(\theta) = 0$, leaving us with no torque.

If we start spinning the platform, and you with it, your motion relative to the outside world is very different. But the initial acceleration relative to the platform is the same. If you didn't cause the stationary platform to spin, you won't change the spin rate of the moving platform.

Comment: Would the platform speed up slightly due to its reduced mass?

Comment: @LaurencePayne No, because you're not just taking your mass with you; you're also taking your kinetic energy. The kinetic energy per mass (half vee squared) remains the same.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - For a speed up to occur, you need to supply a tangential (to the circle) force. Since you are jumping exactly outward, there is none. However, by you jumping out, YOU continue moving in a circular direction (You pick up the radial velocity as well as your existing tangential velocity. This gives you a sort of side-wards travel direction.

Comment: OK.  Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Well, if the merry-go-round is motorized, surely the reduced mass would reduce the load on the motor and allow it to spin faster...

Comment: There is a problem with this answer IMHO - it is over idealised. The impulse imparted when jumping is not instantaneous. The muscles contract over a period of time. When someone jumps radially from a stationary merry-go-round, their sustained push is unidirectional. When jumping from a rotating platform the push-point will move with it. From the POV of the turntable, this will appear to be a twisting motion.   To commence by jumping strictly radially will inevitably  speed up the merry-go-round. You must anticipate slightly and eventually push off slightly late to avoid changing the rotation.

Comment: P.S. The actual amount of the adjustment will depend on the mass of the person relative to the rotational inertia  of the turntable. Also the muscle contraction rate relative to the angular velocity of spin.

Answer (score 16):

I think the problem is using sloppy language and is implying that the person jumps by creating a force in the radial direction.  So the "jump" is radial, but the path after leaving the platform would not be (since the original tangential velocity remains).

Now that I look at your diagram again, I wonder if you are asking about the vertical component of the jump?  The problem is ignoring the vertical component because the platform is constrained to rotate in the horizontal plane.  Any (vertical) torque from the jump is countered by an opposite torque from the rotational hinge.  Only horizontal torques result in angular acceleration of the platform.

When it says "radial", it is (again, I would suggest sloppily) meaning that the horizontal component of the jump forces are in the radial direction, with no tangential component.

Comment: that doesn't make sense, to jump you need to apply a force in a direction perpendicular to disc

Comment: @DDD4C4U, I didn't consider that was what your question was (and I imagine the question author didn't think about it either).  I added some to the answer.

Comment: @DDD4C4U  the force applied in a direction perpendicular to the disc is counter-balanced by the center hinge of the merry-go round. It cannot rotate on this axis.

Answer (score 4):

As he jumps directly outward, with no tangential force, the reaction  force is directly against the axis. So this does not affect the spin rate.

Comment: what do you mean when you say reaction force is directly against the axis? can you show a picture of what you mean?

Comment: Jumping radially would mean his feet pushed off in line with the radius, the axis is the center of the radius, so he applies no  torque on the spin.

Answer (score 3):

The torque is the cross product of the man's position relative to the center of mass, and the force. When the man jumps away, he applies a radial force, meaning the force points at the center of mass, meaning it is parallel to his position vector which also points at the center of mass. The cross product of two parallel vectors is zero.

Answer (score 0):

At the  instant that the person jumps, the impulse they impart is aligned with the radial of the merry-go-round and therefore there is no moment about the rotation axis, hence no effect on the rotational speed.

Comment: I believe the correct English term for "moment" is *torque*. The reason I suspect this is that *torque* is called *momentti* in my native Finnish. I presume the Finnish term is translitterated from either Swedish or German (or both).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen [Moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) and torque are both technical terms in (English) physics. However, [this article](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-torque-and-moment/) may clear things up: "Many forces can be applied to objects, two of which are torque and moment. In physics, they may refer to the same thing, but in mechanical engineering they are different."